# How to block merge when test fail in check PR - iOS

Tags: ios, github, github-actions

I am trying to automate our CI process by using Github Actions.
So far, I achieved to run the test, but how to make the PR check fail and block the merge IF the test are failing?

```
name: myAppname

on: [...]

jobs:
  build_project:
    runs-on: [...]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
 
      - name: Run Tests
        run: |
          xcodebuild \
          -project [...] \
          -scheme [...] \
          -sdk [...] \
          -destination '[...]' \
          test | [...]
```

How should it be the script for the check?